# Symbol meaning any constant number?

Tags: notation

In mathematics, $\Bbb R$ is used to denote the set of all real numbers, and  $\Bbb C$ is used to denote the set of all complex numbers. Is there a symbol used to denote the set of all constant numbers, meaning both real and imaginary?

For example, $c \in \Bbb R$ can be used to state that $c$ exists within the set of real numbers, and $c \in \Bbb C$ can be used to state that $c$ exists within the set of complex numbers.

Is there a symbol used in the same way, $c \in  ?$ to state that $c$ is a constant and never changes? Otherwise, when can it be inferred that the variable in question (in this case $c$) is a constant?

Comment: No since "*number*" without any other context is ambiguous.  As an aside, $\Bbb R$ is used to denote the *set* of real numbers and $\Bbb C$ is used to denote the *set* of complex numbers, not an individual real number or complex number.

Comment: How would you use such a symbol? Depending on what you mean to say, there might be a standard notation, but we can't guess it without context.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I have edited my question to be more descriptive of the question I am asking. I also had previously forgotten how to enter math and I have added correct math into my question

Comment: What do you mean by "any constant number" other than any complex number?  Are you talking about $p$-adic numbers?  Hyperreal numbers?

Comment: I suspect that you are combining two different aspects of using variables.  On one hand we may have information about what "kind" of number (or value) a variable is supposed to represent, as in your examples of real or complex numbers.  On the other hand the role of a symbol plays as "constant" or "varying" could be combined with the other information, but is not exclusive of any particular *domain* of numbers.  An author will need to explain to their Readers when and how a value of a symbol is *fixed* or (alternatively) is allowed to vary.

Comment: Thank you all for the information. @hardmath is there a standard way to communicate that a value is fixed?

Comment: It is an important point to make in writing up proofs to indicate when a value of one symbol *depends* on the value of another symbol.  This is primarily done by careful exposition of the order in which values are chosen, but it is connected with the order of *quantification* in formal logic.  An example is the definition of continuous function in terms of $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$.  That is, the choice of $\delta$ will generally need to *depend* on the choice of $\varepsilon \gt 0$.  Please edit your Question to give a firmer idea of what use you have for "constant" values.

Answer (score 2):

$R,C$ are not really at all standard notations for a real or complex number. I've seen a wide variety of letters to represent real numbers (somewhat moreso $x$ or $y$, sometimes $a$), and often $z$ to represent complex numbers, but I don't believe there is at all a standard notation for these numbers. Names are rather arbitrary after all. I think you might be thinking of $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, which denotes *the sets of* real and complex numbers respectively (as opposed to any single one).

As for something to denote a constant? Use any letter of your choice. About the only letters I would suggest you *don't* choose are those associated with other common constants ($\pi, e, i, \gamma$, etc) - which isn't even really "illegal" as much as it can be confusing for a reader.

I guess if I had to say which I've seen more commonly denoting an arbitrary constant, it would be $c, C, k, a,$ and $A$. But again, it's arbitrary -- aside from well-known constants, it's pretty much completely arbitrary what to name an arbitrary constant; if there is a "standard" for any of these, I'm unaware of it. At best there is just a lot of people using the same variables for the same things for whatever reason, but there's no requirement on that.